# Support multiple authorization filters for one action in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, action-filter

We have an `IAuthorizationFilter` and we can use it to authorize requests.

But there is one problem with it. I have to support multiple authorization filters, e.g.:

1. `BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter`
2. `ApiKeyAuthorizationFilter`

I would get behavior like this:

Firstly, `BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter` checks if authorization header starts with `Bearer`. If not, then if another authorization filter is applicable for current action, then let's run this another authorization filter. If there's no, then return an "HTTP 401 Unauthorized" error.

And the same with `ApiKeyAuthorizationFilter`. At the start, it checks if authorization header starts with `Basic`. If not, checks if another authorization filter exists and if yes then run it. Otherwise, return "HTTP 401 Unauthorized" error.

And to prevent infinite loop we need somehow store information that specific authorization filter was already performed.

It's easy to do in `AuthenticationHandler`. We can return `AuthenticateResult.NoResult()` when specific `AuthenticationHandler` is not applicable to handle this requests and another will run. If all were performed, then return 401 Unauthorized.

So I would have similar mechanism as exists for `AuthenticationHandler` (`AuthenticateResult.NoResult()`). How can I achieve this using `AuthorizationFilter`?

Comment: You can have multiple authorization attributes on your Action or Controller

Comment: I can, but it doesn't work. If one of authorization filters fails, then anothers doesn't run. So I can't support many authorization filters for one action (can't support different authorization methods for one action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for your requirement,there should be three filters

`Scheme Filter` -Check if the auth scheme is correct ,if not correct,return fail

`BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter` -if the scheme is "Bearer",If yes then check the claims from the string ,return fail if claims are not correct

`ApiKeyAuthorizationFilter` -if the scheme is "Basic",If yes then check the user /Password from the string  return fail if user /Password  are not correct

I tried as below:

```
public class SchemeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] Schemes = new string[] { "Bearer", "Basic"};

    private bool exist { get; set; }=false;

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
        {

       
        var str = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        foreach (var scheme in Schemes)
        {
            exist=str.StartsWith(scheme);
           
            if (exist)
            {
               
                break;
            }
           
        }


        }
        if (!exist)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }


    }
}

public class BasicFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string Scheme = "Basic";

   

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var check=context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var value);
         
        if ( value[0].StartsWith(Scheme))
        {
            var basicstr = value[0];
            //modify the logical here yourself
            if (basicstr != "Basic expectedbasicstr")
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class BearerFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

    private readonly string Scheme = "Bearer";
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var check = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var value);
         
        if ( value[0].StartsWith(Scheme))
        {
            var bearerstr = value[0];
            //modify the logical here yourself
            if (bearerstr != "Bearer expectedbearerstr")
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multiple AuthorizeAttribute instances are processed by MVC as if they were joined with AND. If you want an OR behaviour you will need to implement your own logic for checks. Preferably implement AuthAttribute

There are two ways

1. Create custom Auth filter to implement your logic (Recommended)
2. Make your main endpoint receives the request, extract the type and redirect it to respective action for the type of authentication. So now you can look into headers and route to proper auth filter.

Comment: Any examples of first approach? I dont understand how can I achieve OR behavior using custom auth filter if I want many authorization filters on one action to have OR behavior.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-authorization-filter-in-mvc-with-an-example/

Comment: Article which you referred uses ASP NET MVC. It doesn't work in ASP NET Core with NET 7.

Comment: It is just the idea behind it. Here is core version https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.infoworld.com/article/3622962/how-to-use-filters-in-aspnet-core-mvc.amp.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do a `Policy based` Authorization. So for this, you have to write a custom policy. you can check for multiple cases within a single policy

its explained here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0

i have done a similar thing using custom policies like below

```
public sealed class CompanyAccessRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CompanyAccessRequirement>
{
    private readonly ILoggedInUserService _loggedInUserService;
    private readonly IUserSecurityRespository _userSecurityRespository;

    public CompanyAccessRequirementHandler(ILoggedInUserService loggedInUserService, IUserSecurityRespository userSecurityRespository)
    {
        _loggedInUserService = loggedInUserService;
        _userSecurityRespository = userSecurityRespository;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CompanyAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated is false)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var userEmail = _loggedInUserService.UserEmail;

        if (userEmail is null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var user = await _userSecurityRespository.GetUser(context.User);

        if (user is null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }


        var isSuperAdmin = _loggedInUserService.UserId == AppConstants.SuperAdmin.SuperUserId.ToString();

        if (isSuperAdmin)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }

        var hasAccessToCompany = await _userSecurityRespository.HasAccessToCompanies(user.Id, _loggedInUserService.CompanyIds);

        if (hasAccessToCompany)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if I have specified multiple policies in `[Authorize]` attribute? Are they ANDed or ORed ? I cant find information about it. And if they ANDed, how can I achieve OR behavior?

Comment: Its policies are evaluated on `And` conditons

Comment: Policies aren't working because I don't have any authentication scheme. My API is not interested in "who requested", but rather "does given API key is valid".

Comment: okay, you can write  a middle where to intercept an http request and check if API key is available or any other stuff that you need to validate if the request is valid

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Using middle I cannot achieve ORed authorization support :/. Seems I can only write different types of authorization in one middle or something else. But this is an ugly approach for me.